# MySQLi Prepared is not working UPDATE Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have here my codes the should change the status of the specific crew once I click the submit button. but when I click the button, it gives me an FALSE result. can someone tell me what the problem is?

below is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$crew = 'NEW';
$query_update = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `crew_status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query_update);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ss', $_GET['id'],$crew);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt2) !== 0) {
        echo "Crew update accepted";
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_stmt_affected_rows shouldn't be used to detect errors.

Change your code to this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$query_update = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `crew_status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query_update);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ss', $_GET['id'],$crew);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
echo "Crew update accepted";
```

Comment: where is the if statement?

Comment: You didn't ask for the if statement. You asked why your update is not working.

Comment: i tried your code but UPDATE still not working. can you please include the if statement please?

Comment: how can I fix it? because everytime I run it it gives me false result?

Comment: **What** is giving you a "false" result? What is this result? Does it say Crew update accepted?

Comment: this one gives me the "Crew update accepted"
(!mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt2))

Comment: There shouldn't be an else statement, as well as if statement. What error you are looking for?

Comment: logical error i guess. because when i run the codes the query does not update

Comment: Describe "does not update". What are values in the database? What are values you are trying to update? What are values after update? How did you get them?

Comment: um trying to update the colum `crew_status` in table `crew_info`. once i click the ubmit button, the NEW will be updated to the `crew_status`

Comment: and so what is the status of crew_status in the database?

Comment: before you click the button, that 'PENDING' after you click the button, that must be change into 'NEW'

Comment: How do you know that? And hat is the value of $_GET['id'] when you run your query?

Comment: the value of $_GET['id'] is 6 depends on what data